# mysql : Any command to use instead of mysql_insert_id(); in PHP?

Tags: mysql, lastinsertid

I want to get primarykey ID of just insert item. In PHP has mysql_insert_id(). I write in C#

Comment: What database access technology are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cmd  is your command object try:

```
  cmd.LastInsertId;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to query the database directly.

```
SELECT last_insert_id() FROM mytable;
```

So say with ODBC

```
object lastID = new OdbcCommand("SELECT last_insert_id() FROM mytable", _connection).ExecuteScalar();
```